# Set SQL Stored Procedure path in Azure Logical App using a variable value

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am most of the way through a Logic App but have got stuck on the below line of code that aims to insert the path to the sp required from json parsed in the previous step of ReportTabQuery:

```
"path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[@body('ReportTabQuery')?['query']]'))}"
```

The error is as below:

> Unable to parse template language expression
>   'encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[@body('ReportTabQuery')?['query']]'))':
>   expected token 'RightParenthesis' and actual 'Identifier'.".'.

I think this is about escaping the single quotes like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730162/string-concatenation-issue-with-azure-logic-apps) but I can't seem to work it out.  All that changes is the token required and position values.  I have tried the following so far and other variants such as concat():

```
"path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[@{body('ReportTabQuery')?['query']}]'))}"

"path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent({'[dbo].[@body('ReportTabQuery')?['query']]'}))}"
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, you will need to concatenate the variable value to the other parts:

```
"path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(concat('[dbo].[', body('ReportTabQuery')?['query'], ']')))}"
```

BTW, I don't think you need `encodeURIComponent` twice:

```
"path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(concat('[dbo].[', body('ReportTabQuery')?['query'], ']'))}"
```

HTH

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the answer. I am going to try that now.