# how to concatenate string with triggerbody?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've been attempting to concatenate:

```
@{concat('/',parameters('embedAttachmentsContainerDone'),'/','/@{triggerBody()?[''Properties'']?[''DestinationFileName'']})}
```

I've also tried:

```
@concat('/',parameters('embedAttachmentsContainerDone'),'/','/@{triggerBody()?[''Properties'']?[''DestinationFileName'']})
```

Sometimes I will get a deploy error, other times I'm getting an error while running the logic app. Other times, I am getting a very weird message:

[image]

```
@{concat('/',parameters('embedAttachmentsContainerDone'),'/',triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DestinationFileName'])}
```

**How do we concatonate a string, with a parameter, with triggerBody?**

Answer (score 1):

You may have a try with this expression:**concat('/',parameters('embedAttachmentsContainerDone'),'/@{triggerBody()?[''Properties'']?[''DestinationFileName'']')**. In the third expression which you shared above, please use '' in front of Properties and behind the Properties, and put /@{triggerBody()?[''Properties'']?[''DestinationFileName''] in a pair of single quotes. You can also refer to this ticket: [String concatenation issue with Azure Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730162/string-concatenation-issue-with-azure-logic-apps)